# vs code extension are not working properly?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My vs code extension are not working properly. It work only for sometime then it stop working.i had uninstall and install many times but its not working.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading vs code. It resolved similar problem for some people. (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71998)

Comment: Not likely applicable because this issue is about VSC 1.32/33 (almost a year ago) and we currently are at v1.41